socket.io server side with express, create socket.on on express endpoint
var esocket;

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  esocket = socket //works intermittent 
})

app.get('/launchtask', (req, res) => {
    var taskID = CreateID()

    // or should it have been ?
    esocket = io.sockets.sockets.get('req.body.socketid')
    // doesn't seem to work either.


    esocket.on('taskID',(result) => {
      io.emit('taskID', result)
    })
  
})



I wonder if it's the correct way of using socket outside of io.on() ?
I want server to listen to worker to long running result and broadcast to web client with an ID.
worker.js
socket.emit(taskId, blah)

frontend.js
socket.on(taskId, ...



I wonder if it's the correct way of using socket outside of io.on() ?

No, it is not correct.  This type of code will not work in a server that serves multiple users.  You're jamming a socket from a particular client into a module-level variable and then attempting to use that LATER when an incoming request is made that may or may not be from that same client.
This type of design will not work properly in a server with more than one possible client.
Since your question does not describe the actual problem you're trying to solve (it just shows placeholder code), we can't really advise what a solution would be.

Decided to redesign using rooms
server:
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  socket.join(socket.id)
  socket.on('results', (result) => { 
    io.to(result.room).emit('result', result)
  })
})

frontend:
socket.on('result', (result) => {})

worker:
socket.emit('results', {room:socketid, data:...})

